# multibar property gives access violation

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007, teechart

I am creating a barseries programmatically (Delphi2007, TeeChar 7 free edition). I'd like to have adjacent bars in my graph, so I try to create multiple barseries and use the multibar property.

When setting multibar property in main_unit, I get access violation (when debugging, if I inspect the barseries object, I can see the multibar property as "out of bound"). 
I don't get the error only if I set the property in the unit where the barseries was created. How I can manipulate the barseries externally? Do I have to set a property fotr this purpose in unit1?

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
unit unit1 
type TMyChart = Class
fchart: TChart;
procedure addSinglebarSeries(var X, Y: integer)    
....
implementation
function TSignalchart.addSinglebarSeries(var X, Y: integer): TBarSeries;
j, n : integer;   
begin
   result := TBarSeries.Create(fChart);
   result.AddXY(x,Y,inttostr(x), clRed);
   barseries.MultiBar := mbStacked;  //here no access violation
end;

---- 
unit main-unit

implementation
uses TeEngine, TeeProcs, unit1;
procedure myprocedure;
var 
 newChart : TMyChart;
 X, Y := array of integer;
 barseries : TBarSeries;
 aX, aY, i: integer;

begin
 //I create the newchart object, I create X, Y

  for i := 0 to length(X) - 1 do
    begin
      aX := X[i];
      aY := Y[i];
      barseries := newChart.addsinglebarSeries(aX,aY);
    end;
   //barseries.MultiBar := mbStacked; //access violation!!
  end;
```

Comment: Just to clarify: Is it Delphi 7 (from tags) or 2007 (from text)?

Comment: Sorry, it's Delphi 2007 (I've just edited the tag)

Comment: I have edited the question, because I found that acceding the multibar propert from the same unit where the object was declared didn't give access violation. So, for now, I'll go on editing my methods in unit1

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of adding 5 multibar stacked series in a `TeeChart` (D2007). `Chart1` is a `TChart` component dropped from the component palette, and `Button1` is a standard `TButton` placed the same way:

```
// D2007+ way to easily initialize dynamic arrays
type
  TIntArray=array of Integer;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  BarSeries: TBarSeries;
  X, Y: TIntArray;
  i: Integer;
begin
  X := TIntArray.Create(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);       // SetLength and initialize rolled into one
  Y := TIntArray.Create(10, 20, 30, 40, 50);  // Nonsense values, of course.
  Chart1.SeriesList.Clear;
  for i := Low(X) to High(X) do
  begin
    BarSeries := TBarSeries.Create(Chart1);
    BarSeries.AddXY(X[i], Y[i]);
    BarSeries.MultiBar := mbStacked;
    Chart1.AddSeries(BarSeries);
  end;
end;
```

Here's the form after clicking `Button1`:

[image]